# Re-plotting contour filled plot using a PatchCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to display a filled contour plot using the collection coming from an original other contourplot. However, I am missing something as my code does not exactly reproduce the contour plot.

Minimal code I am working on:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection, PolyCollection

x = np.arange(0, 300,1)
y = np.arange(0, 300,1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(y, x)
Topo = np.cos(X*2*np.pi/50)*np.sin(Y*2*np.pi/200)*y

plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

Ncolors = 50
levels = np.linspace(np.min(Topo),np.max(Topo),Ncolors)
# h = plt.contourf(X,Y, Topo, levels = levels, cmap = cmap, vmin = 0.85*np.min(Topo), zorder = -10)
h = plt.contourf(Y, X, Topo, levels = levels)

ax = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

i = 0
for levellines in h.collections:
    for lines in levellines.get_paths():
        plt.gca().add_collection(PatchCollection( [ Polygon( lines.vertices ) ] , facecolor = levellines.get_facecolor()[0], edgecolor = levellines.get_facecolor()[0]) )
    i = i+1
plt.xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
plt.ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
```

[image]
As you may ask why I am trying to passe thourgh a the Polygon function and the path vertices: later, I will need to change a little bit the coordinates of the vertices `lines.vertices` to make some projections, changing view points, etc ..

Note that the result highly depend on the plotted surface .. Sometimes no artefact appear, sometimes it is much worse than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to found the problem. The artefacts appear when the paths contained in `lines` are not simple paths, but bezier curves or others.

Therfore, you need to plot paths instead of polygons to add this information contained in the `codes` attribute.

Juste use :

```
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
```

and then :

```
plt.gca().add_patch(patches.PathPatch( Path(lines.vertices, lines.codes) , facecolor = levellines.get_facecolor()[0], edgecolor = levellines.get_facecolor()[0]) )
```

instead of

```
 plt.gca().add_collection(PatchCollection( [ Polygon( lines.vertices ) ] , facecolor = levellines.get_facecolor()[0], edgecolor = levellines.get_facecolor()[0]) )
```

Finally, you can also convert the paths to Polygons using `.to_polygons()`:

```
 plt.gca().add_collection(PatchCollection( [ Polygon( lines.to_polygons() ) ] , facecolor = levellines.get_facecolor()[0], edgecolor = levellines.get_facecolor()[0]) )
```